# Hello everyone. i have getUserData method in Main class. i want to call this method from the main class. can anyone help me?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

i have getUserData method in Main class. i want to call this method from the main class. can anyone help me?

```java
public List<User> getUserData(){
    User user1 =new User(0,"Rezo Joglidze");
    User user2 =new User(1,"Galaktion Tabidze");
    User user3 =new User(2,"Ilia Chavchavadze");

    userList.add(user1);
    userList.add(user2);
    userList.add(user3);

    return userList;
}
```

Comment: from where do you want the function to be called? Can you share the code? How do you initialize `Main` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the method `getUserData` is located in a class called `Main` it can be called like follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> userData = new Main().getUserData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you can go about this depends entirely on your use case. Since the code you've provided doesn't need to pull from other classes in a non-static way, try using the `static` keyword to be able to call it from main. Try this out for size:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> userData = Main.getUserData();
    }

    public static List<User> getUserData(){
        User user1 = new User(0, "Rezo Joglidze");
        User user2 = new User(1, "Galaktion Tabidze");
        User user3 = new User(2, "Ilia Chavchavadze");

        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);
        userList.add(user3);

        return userList;
    }
}
```